# Cannot log into new user account

Tags: login, password

I am trying to set up a user account for my girlfriend on Ubuntu 14.04. Every time I try to set it up, the account is created with the right name, but I cannot get the account to log in. If I set the account up with no password, the screen flashes a few times like it is trying to log in and then returns to the login screen. If I assign a password to the account, the password (entered case-sensitive) is rejected as incorrect. I have tried doing this through both command terminal and the system settings panel. The commands I have used in terminal are: `useradd [username]` and `useradd -p [password] [username]`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try creating it through the GUI. (It should be in system settings somewhere)

Comment: I have tried the settings panel in the GUI. It gives the exact same result as using the terminal.